# why the application is recreated but the activity's onCreate still has the savedInstanceState passed in

Tags: android, dagger, onsaveinstancestate

Having a bug which relate to the os kill/restore the activity (or the app?).

After some debug find if set `don't keep activities` and set `Background process limit` to `no background process` will cause different behavior.

saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39587541/what-is-the-difference-between-dont-keep-activities-and-background-processs-lim), but it does not answer the question here.

Here is what observed:

In the application it will start dagger component and it maintains some app scope singleton object, and in activity A (the default launch activity) it will by user's action to launch activity B, in B it creates and hosts a fragment. There will be some data stored in the app scope singleton object to work with the fragment.

In case of only have the `don't keep activities` set,  when minimize the app the activities onDestroy() is called, and when re-open the app it restores the last active activity (say the user opened the activity B, the B will be re-created with the fragment restored with the savedInstanceState). In this case the app scope singleton objects managed by the dagger are still alive, so the state is completely restored to what it was before minimized the app.

But if have both `don't keep activities` and set `Background process limit` to `no background process`, then when minimize the app, the activity's onDestroy() is not call (only call up to the onStop()).

The behavior change is at this time if re-open the app,  it will start from application onCreate(), and recreate the dagger's component. So the state before minimize the app is not re-stored.

But the os seems still remembers the last activity is B and the B's

```
onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
```

is called with savedInstanceState having the data saved when minimizing the app, so does B's fragment.

And it is a messed up,  it has data from the savedInstanceState, but the app scope singleton objects are fresh ones that do not have the data to work with the ones from the savedInstanceState.

Anyone knows in this case where is the savedInstance saved, and why although the application seems to be recreated but still the last activity (not the launching activity) is re-stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `savedInstanceState` bundle is explicitly intended to do as you describe. Regardless of whether a background activity is destroyed to conserve memory (e.g. "don't keep activities" is turned on) or whether an entire app process is killed to conserve memory (e.g. "background process limit" is zero), the framework will provide your app the ability to save state information into the `savedInstanceState` bundle and will subsequently return that state information to you in future calls to `onCreate()`.

The *only* situation in which `savedInstanceState` will be `null` is the very first time your activity starts up. It doesn't matter whether your app's process is killed or not; if your activity is restored you will receive a non-null `savedInstanceState` bundle.

Comment: Thanks Ben!   the http://www.developerphil.com/dont-store-data-in-the-application-object/ also helps.